# How to get the value of an XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file:

```
<SourceMessage xmlns="test.test">
  <updated>2011</updated>
  <title type="p1"/>
  <title type="p2"/>
  <title type="p3"/>
  <entry>
  </entry>
</SourceMessage>
```

How could I use LINQ to get the <type> attribute of the <title> element, i.e. "p1", "p2" and "p3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) or [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) to load the XML data into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). Then, using LINQ, you can get the type for each <title> element under the document root as follows:

```
XNamespace test = "test.test";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
// - or -
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<SourceMessage ...");

IEnumerable<string> query = from title in doc.Root.Elements(test + "title")
                            select (string)title.Attribute("type");

foreach (string item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

*Output:*

```
p1
p2
p3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xElement XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var result = xElement.Descendants("title")
                     .Select(e => e.Attribute("type").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse (@"<SourceMessage xmlns="test.test">
<updated>2011</updated>
  <title type="p1"/>
  <title type="p2"/>
  <title type="p3"/>
  <entry>
  </entry>
</SourceMessage>");

foreach (var t in xml.Root.Descendants("title"))
    Console.Write(t.Attribute("type").Value);
```